# Fastest way to create mapped matrix in numpy

Tags: function, numpy, matrix

I have the following problem. I have a 2D numpy matrix of integers, let's say they're in the range 0-19. The matrix has shape (r, c). Call this matrix M. I have an additional array, a lookup table, A, of length 19 whose elements are small numpy vectors, each with length N. What I want to do is to create a new matrix of shape (r, c, N) where I've replaced the integer in the original matrix by it's lookup table counterpart.

Simple enough, it's just a function on a matrix which produces a new matrix with an additional dimension. I have written code for this which looks like:

```
num_rows, num_cols = M.shape
result = np.zeros(num_rows, num_cols, 3)

for col in range(num_cols):
    for row in range(num_ros):
        idx = M[row, col]
        result[row, col] = np.array(A[idx])
```

This works but the problem is it's is too slow. If M has 500,000 elements then it takes like 600ms per matrix which is the bottleneck in my code. There has to be a clever numpy way of handling this which is faster but I can't think of it.

Comment: What does `A[M]` produce?

Comment: yes thank you, that is the solution. One of my coworkers also found it!